# Unir o resultado de uma query na mesma linha a partir do sequencial

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM SERQUENCIAL 
WHERE DATA BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-19'
```

Ela retorna:

```
+--------------+-------+------------+-----------------------+
| ID_PESS NOME | DATA  | DATA_HORA  |      SEQUENCIAL       |
+--------------+-------+------------+-----------------------+
|         8788 | JOAO  | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-01 13:01:01 1 |
|         8788 | JOAO  | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-01 15:07:01 2 |
|         8788 | JOAO  | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-01 17:08:01 3 |
|         8788 | JOAO  | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-01 19:03:01 4 |
|         8533 | MARIA | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-03 11:01:01 1 |
|         8533 | MARIA | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-03 14:07:01 2 |
|         8533 | MARIA | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-03 16:08:01 3 |
|         8533 | MARIA | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-03 18:03:01 4 |
|         8935 | JOSE  | 2017-01-05 | 2017-01-05 13:01:01 1 |
|         8935 | JOSE  | 2017-01-05 | 2017-01-05 19:07:01 2 |
|         8935 | JOSE  | 2017-01-05 | 2017-01-05 20:08:01 3 |
|         8935 | JOSE  | 2017-01-05 | 2017-01-05 22:03:01 4 |
|         8935 | JOSE  | 2017-01-05 | 2017-01-05 23:03:01 5 |
+--------------+-------+------------+-----------------------+
```

Como faço para unir os retornos por pessoa da seguinte forma por exemplo:

```
+---------+------+------------+---------------------+------+---------------------+------+---------------------+------+---------------------+------+
| ID_PESS | NOME |    DATA    |    DATA_HORA_01     | SEQ1 |    DATA_HORA_02     | SEQ2 |    DATA_HORA_03     | SEQ3 |    DATA_HORA_04     | SEQ4 |
+---------+------+------------+---------------------+------+---------------------+------+---------------------+------+---------------------+------+
|    8788 | JOAO | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-01 13:01:01 |    1 | 2017-01-01 15:07:01 |    2 | 2017-01-01 17:08:01 |    3 | 2017-01-01 19:03:01 |    4 |
+---------+------+------------+---------------------+------+---------------------+------+---------------------+------+---------------------+------+
```

Ou seja, os dados da pessoa juntos na mesma linha.

> **Observação**:
>
> Os dados da pessoa podem se repetir em outro dia. Caso aconteça será
> uma nova linha da pessoa.

Comment: Não seria possível utilizar o `Group by` na coluna `ID_PESS`

Comment: Não porque ai vai unir e não iria listar os outros campos data e sequencial

Comment: Algumas dúvidas, o Sequencial pode ser quebrado em dois campos? Um com o date e outro com o incremento? Esse número final é gerado como, a partir da aplicação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando-se que o número de linhas por pessoa/data é variável, a solução ideal deve empregar o uso de pivoteamento com comando SQL dinâmico.
Eis solução que funciona com nível de compatibilidade 80 (SQL Server 2000) em diante.

```
-- código #1 v4
-- define período de emissão
declare @DataInicial date, @DataFinal date;
set @DataInicial= Convert(date, '1/1/2017', 103);
set @DataFinal= Convert(date, '19/1/2017', 103);

-- obtém maior valor de sequencial
declare @maxSequencial int, @I int;
set @maxSequencial= (SELECT max(SEQUENCIAL) from tabela);

-- monta o comando sql dinâmico
declare @SQL nvarchar(4000);

set @SQL= N'SELECT ID_PESS, NOME, DATA, ';

set @I= 1;
while (@I <= @maxSequencial)
     begin
     set @SQL+= N'max(case when SEQUENCIAL = ' + 
                Cast(@I as nvarchar) + 
                N' then Cast(DATA_HORA as smalldatetime) end) as [' + 
                Cast(@I as nvarchar) + N'], ';
     set @I+= 1;
     end;
set @SQL= Left(@SQL, Len(@SQL) -1);     

set @SQL+= N' from tabela where DATA between @Data1 and @Data2' +
           N' group by ID_PESS, NOME, DATA;';
--
--print @SQL
Execute sp_executesql @stmt= @SQL, 
                      @params=N'@Data1 datetime, @Data2 datetime',
                      @Data1= @DataInicial, @Data2= @DataFinal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde.

Eu faria o seguinte:
1- não deixaria o nome do empregado/cliente/empregado, mas usaria o ID deles (previna os homônimos); e
2- tu fará uma busca com INNER JOIN (não sei como funciona no SQL Server).

Lembre-se que todo sequencial possui um ID e dependendo do tipo de relatório que tu gerará, vale a pena tê-lo. Já para ordenação, utilize um ORDER BY composto pelo ID (prevenindo homônimos) e o número sequencial.

Answer (score 0):

@José Diz , 
 Optei por essa que também foi uma dica sua, pois precisei implementar mais coisas na consulta e rodou bem com ela. Obrigado pela ajuda.

```
-- código #2 v2
-- define período de emissão (formato dd/mm/aaaa)
declare @DataInicial date, @DataFinal date;
set @DataInicial= Convert(date, '1/1/2017', 103);
set @DataFinal= Convert(date, '19/1/2017', 103);

--
SELECT ID_PESS, NOME, DATA,
       max(case when SEQUENCIAL = 1 then Cast(DATA_HORA as smalldatetime) end) as [1],
       max(case when SEQUENCIAL = 2 then Cast(DATA_HORA as smalldatetime) end) as [2],
       max(case when SEQUENCIAL = 3 then Cast(DATA_HORA as smalldatetime) end) as [3],
       max(case when SEQUENCIAL = 4 then Cast(DATA_HORA as smalldatetime) end) as [4],
       max(case when SEQUENCIAL = 5 then Cast(DATA_HORA as smalldatetime) end) as [5],
       max(case when SEQUENCIAL > 5 then 'MAIS DE 5 DATAS!' else '' end) as [Obs]
  from tabela
  where DATA between @DataInicial and @DataFinal
  group by ID_PESS, NOME, DATA;
```